# Can someone help me get rid of overlapping freestyle lines?

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

so I am trying to make this scene with a helicopter flying through a city with freestyle lines to make it still look cartoony, since I am doing this for a 2D animated feature.

For some reason it keeps making the lines of the building overlap with the helicopter and it looks annoying when you render it.

What settings do I have to put to make it so that I can make the overlapping lines disappear and just have the helicopter's body lines in front?

Here are my settings for freestyle lines

[image]

Thank you.

[image: How do I get rid of these lines and just have the helicopter be in front instead of the building's freestyle lines?]

Comment: Could you better describe your scene and show your freestyles settings?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nPbIxgw.png